# NSCalendar returns the wrong day of the week

Tags: objective-c, nscalendar

I have this code that takes the name of the weekday with the values ​​that are provided, today is August 10, 2014 and should return Sunday, but the code is returning Tuesday, why?

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

        NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [dateComponents setWeekday:10];
        [dateComponents setWeekdayOrdinal:1];
        [dateComponents setYear:2014];
        [dateComponents setMonth:8];

        NSDate *tempDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];

        NSString *retval = [format stringFromDate:tempDate];

        NSLog(@"Today -> %@",retval);
```

Comment: Log tempDate as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136796/nscalendar-datefromcomponents-returns-wrong-date-by-2 - use setDay

Comment: (Divide 10 by 7 and you get a remainder of 3.)

Comment: @HotLicks, so in your simulator the slog retval returns sunday, instead of tuesday?

Comment: Thanks mans! I use setDay and works as well thanks

Comment: Log tempDate and you will see that the date is a Tuesday (probably the first one) in August.  This is because you're setting the day of the week rather than the day of the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of problems with your code. First of all `weekday` property can be a number from 1 to 7 in case of the gregorian calendar.

From [NSDateComponents documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateComponents/weekdayOrdinal):

> Weekday units are the numbers 1 through n, where n is the number of days in the week. For example, in the Gregorian calendar, n is 7 and Sunday is represented by 1.

So if you want to create `NSDateComponents` which represent  sunday you have to set `weekDay` property value to 1.

You have to change value of the `weekdayOrdinal` property too.

From [NSDateComponents documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateComponents/weekdayOrdinal):

> Weekday ordinal units represent the position of the weekday within the next larger calendar unit, such as the month. For example, 2 is the weekday ordinal unit for the second Friday of the month.

In you case you have to set its value to 2 because you want to create `NSDateComponents` for the second Sunday of the month.

Here is changed code:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setWeekday:1];
[dateComponents setWeekdayOrdinal:2];
[dateComponents setYear:2014];
[dateComponents setMonth:8];
```

That being said, it is probably simple to just use `day` property and forget about `weekday` and `weekdayOrdinal` properties at all:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setDay:10];
[dateComponents setYear:2014];
[dateComponents setMonth:8];
```